# Dockerize Django Websocket Url not found

Tags: django, docker, websocket, django-channels

I have a project with Django using Websocket and I'm using a docker. I have configuration named local.yml and used `uvicorn` and `channels`. When I started to build my docker, the http request works fine but my websocket urls is not found 404 error.

Here is my local.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: api_local_django
    container_name: api_local_django
    platform: linux/x86_64
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    # command: /start
    command: uvicorn config.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0
    # command: uvicorn config.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 300 --chdir=/app    
    # /usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 300 --chdir=/app
    
  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: api_production_postgres
    container_name: api_local_postgres
    volumes:
      - ./api_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./api_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432"
  redis:
    image: redis:6
    container_name: api_local_redis

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: api_local_celeryworker
    container_name: api_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: api_local_celerybeat
    container_name: api_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: api_local_flower
    container_name: api_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

Now above, I tried to start using uvicorn and it has no errors. Now here is my asgi file which handles the http request and the websocket requests.

```
import os
import sys

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from pathlib import Path

import config.routing

# This allows easy placement of apps within the interior
# apps directory.
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
sys.path.append(str(ROOT_DIR / "apps"))

# We specify the correct module and attribute for the ASGI application.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.production")
asgi_application = get_asgi_application()


application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": asgi_application,
        "websocket": URLRouter(config.routing.websocket_urlpatterns), 
    }
)
```

Here is my routing file which handles the routes of my websocket urls:

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from apps.test.consumers import TestConsumer
from django.conf.urls import url


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/test/$', TestConsumer.as_asgi()),   
]
```

In my settings.py i've already added the channels in Installed apps and also added the `channel_layer` and `ASGI_APPLICATION`

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "config.asgi.application"
INSTALLED_APPS = ["channels"]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [{"redis://redis:6379/1", 6379}],
        },
        "ROUTING": "config.routing.websocket_urlpatterns"
    },
}
```

Is there any missing settings that i've missed? Or is there wrong with the config?
I'm using the channel version of 4.0.0

I tried firing the websocket url below in postman websocket request and i got 404 error

```
ws:://localhost:8000/ws/test/
```

Comment: tried? `pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'`

Comment: i just installed uvicorn, i will try your suggestion.

Comment: hmm i got error 500 now, but i don't know where this error comes. I have no logs when i tried to log my django server

Comment: but my http requests are working good

Comment: so no more failed to connect ws? but returning 500?